# ruby dynamically change method while keeping original type signature

Tags: ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming

My aim is to take an existing function, `foo`, and create an exact copy of it called `bar`, which is simple enough with `alias_method`. I would then like to dynamically redefine `foo` such that it has the exact same type signature, so that I can call `bar` from it, among other reasons.

This requirements mean that I cannot just do something like

```
define_method(:foo) do |*args, &block|
    send(:bar, *args, &block)
end
```

because it changes the type signature of `foo`.

I also don't see how I can use something like `method(:foo).parameters` as that will tell me what the type signature is, but will not specify, for example, the values of default arguments.

Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with wrapping a method, but your method should use duck-typing rather than "type signatures."

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has no concept of manifest types and manifest type signatures. Since they don't exist, you obviously can't get them.

When doing Ruby programming, there *is* of course a *latent* concept of types and type signatures *in the programmer's head*. But that's exactly where that concept exists: in the programmer's head and *only* in the programmer's head.

It *might* also exist in documentation, but that is not guarateed. Also, there is no standard format for putting it in documentation. There are various different formats for expressing types in Ruby documentation, sometimes the types are not expressed using any form of (semi-)formal notation at all, but only in prose, and sometimes, they are implicit in the names of parameters. In some cases, the types are just part of the Ruby culture, everybody knows them, but they are never actually written down anywhere (the most obvious example is the `each` protocol that the `Enumerable` mixin depends on, which everybody "just knows" without being explicitly specified).

You are also asking about default arguments for optional parameters: these are evaluated dynamically, getting static information about them is simply impossible because of the Halting Problem, Rice's Theorem and all the other fun undecidability results in programming.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Ruby doesn't care about types. It only cares about whether or not an object can [#respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) a message. As a result, any hard-wired expectations about types should be encoded in method/variable names, and in the documentation.

### Use Duck-Typing to Wrap Methods

The "Ruby way" is to use duck-typing rather than strict "type signatures." While there's nothing wrong with wrapping a method, your methods should:

1. Use meaningful argument names, if the type of an argument matters.
2. Perform implicit or explicit coercion or define singleton methods in the cases where you need an object to [#respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) a method it doesn't currently support.
3. Implement singleton methods when necessary to permit duck-typing.

For example:

```
def foo array
  array.is_a? Array
end

def flexible_foo string_or_array
  if string_or_array.respond_to? :split
    array = string_or_array.split /,?\s+/
  else
    array = string_or_array
  end
  foo array
end

flexible_foo 'a, b, c'
#=> true

flexible_foo %w[a b c]
#=> true
```

In this example, #foo expects an array. By wrapping #foo, we create a work-alike method that coerces the value into an array if it responds to the :split message, which String does and Array does not.

### Documentation

Both RDoc and [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) do a reasonable job of documenting method signatures "out of the box," but YARD also has [support for using tags](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Tag_Syntax) to document things like "type signatures" and return types.

If your code is written with fixed expectations about what kinds of objects can be passed as arguments, then you can document those expectations in comments which RDoc or YARD will dutifully report. However, this is considered to be the programmer's responsibility rather than the Ruby interpreter's, and you'll know if you've broken the implicit contract when Ruby raises a [NoMethodError exception](http://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html) at runtime.

This is one reason the Ruby community embraces test-driven development: since Ruby can redefine methods and classes on the fly, the interpreter won't know until runtime whether the calling method has sent an invalid message or not. This is generally considered a Good Thing®, but your mileage and opinions may certainly vary.